# Adding parameter to an asset?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sprockets

in a Rails application I'd like to generate html tags for javascript files including a query parameter. Currently the app uses Sprockets library for such task.

in assets/javascript directory there are:

```
jquery.fbbox.js
all.js
```

all.js contains `//= require ./jquery.fbbox.js` and is processed with Sprockets to generate html tag

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.fbbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I would like to pass some extra parameter like *ver=3.0.4* to get

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.fbbox.js?ver=3.0.4" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How can I direct sprockets to do this for me ?
I've tried to add an argument to require like `//= require ./jquery.fbbox.js, :ver => '3.0.4'` but that's fails with syntax error.

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: Came across this issue today in while trying to load the MathJax library.  Did you find a way to do this using Rails?

Answer (score 0):

You could save separate versions of the library you're importing with version numbers in the filename and then serve them with a separate import statement in the manifest like so:

`//= require ./jquery.fbbox-3.0.4.js`

or in layouts/application.html.erb

`<script src="/assets/jquery.fbbox-<%= fbbox_version_number %>.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

There are a number of ways to handle this